# Como salvar em um único vetor, classes bases e derivadas?

Tags: array, c++, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um trabalho em C++, e preciso gravar em um único vetor, uma classe base, e duas derivadas. Como fazer fazer esse vetor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse tipo de problema é solucionado através de um [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Quando você tem um ponteiro para o objeto fica fácil lidar com isso porque o vetor só terá os ponteiros, então não importa se ele tem o objeto base ou qualquer dos derivados. A única exigência é que o objeto apontado seja do tipo base ou derivado dele, só por questão de segurança de tipo e não poder colocar um pão em um vetor de animais.

Se não quer usar indireção aí complica. De forma fácil e natural não tem como. Teria que criar um mecanismo para tratar isso manualmente, e duvido que compense. Você terá que guardar em cada elemento do vetor o objeto e de que tipo ele é, e lidar com cada elemento de acordo com o tipo. Sem isso corre o risco de pegar um objeto como se fosse outro com uma estrutura inadequada. Esse fenômeno é chamado de [*slicing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286437/101). Para o vetor ter tamanho fixo ele adotará o tamanho do tipo base, se o tipo derivado for maior, o excesso será descartado. Nem tente.

Comment: Fiquei em dúvida da interpretação exata do que seria o _slicing_ nesse caso. Abri uma pergunta sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286437/64969