# O que é o "fenômeno slicing" ao tentar ler dados de um array com tipos heterogêneo?

Tags: array, c++

Estava curiosamente lendo uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286412/64969) sobre como armazenar tipos heterogêneos em um array quando me deparo com o seguinte trecho da resposta:

> Você terá que guardar em cada elemento do vetor o objeto e de que tipo ele é, e lidar com cada elemento de acordo com o tipo. Sem isto corre o risco de pegar um objeto como se fosse outro com uma estrutura inadequada. Este fenômeno é chamado de *slicing*.

Interpretei aqui que *slicing* seria o "corte" inadequado de informações no vetor, fazendo com que o objeto obtido através desses bytes na melhor das hipóteses não faça sentido. Minha interpretação foi algo assim:

```
Bytes separados por objetos reais
| b0   b1   b2 | b3   b4 | b5   b6 |
Slicing decorrente da leitura errada
| b0   b1 | b2   b3   b4 | b5   b6 |
```

Os dois primeiros objetos lidos diferem da leitura correta e da leitura com *slicing*.

Então, minhas dúvidas são:

- Essa interpretação acima está correta?
- O problema do *slicing* aparenta acontecer também em C pelos mesmos motivos; em quais linguagens* ele é mais aparente? Tem linguagens virtualmente blindadas contra esse efeito?
- O *slicing* pode ocorrer dentro de um vetor de dados homogêneos? Ou ele está restrito a dados heterogêneos?

  <sup>*: não precisa ser uma lista exaustiva, bastaria definir que linguagens que seguem a característica `x` são sucetíveis a esse fenômeno</sup>

Comment: Não quis entrar em detalhes lá, a pergunta é muito pertinente aqui, vou explicar melhor o fenômeno.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Slicing* existe em vários contextos da computação. Estou falando do *slice* de um objeto. Isso costuma acontecer em linguagens orientadas a objeto. Ali o exemplo foi em vetor, mas não confunda com o [*slicing* de coleções de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) que é algo deliberado que o programador manda fazer. Estou falando de algo que ocorre inadvertidamente em objetos.

> Essa interpretação acima está correta?

A ideia é essa, mas não exatamente assim, pelo menos dentro do que eu conheço. Pode até ser que isso possa ocorrer em alguma situação, mas nunca vi algo como o mostrado (pode ser desconhecimento meu).

O *slicing* costuma acontecer entre tipos com relação de herança.

> O problema do *slicing* aparenta acontecer também em C pelos mesmos motivos; em quais linguagens* ele é mais aparente? Tem linguagens virtualmente blindadas contra esse efeito?

O fenômeno ocorre inadvertidamente em linguagens de tipagem fraca ([não confundir com tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101)). Claro que em linguagens de tipagem forte é possível reproduzir o fenômeno se ela permitir explicitamente que troque o tipo de um objeto sem uma conversão. Isso é raro em linguagens modernas, mesmo que compile quando faz isso deve dar um erro e não chega apresentar o *slicing*. Por linguagens modernas entenda como linguagens gerenciadas. De certa forma só essas linguagens podem ser consideradas completamente fortes na tipagem, mas isso é outro assunto.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca e poderia ocorrer o fenômeno, porém ela não tem relação de herança. Ocorreria problemas semelhantes e até mais graves se o código quiser mesmo, mas não exatamente o *slicing*. O exemplo mostrado na pergunta faz algo mais grave, mas para ele ocorrer precisa algum esforço ;) O código tem que pedir para ele ocorrer.

Em C, e em certa medida em C++, dependendo do estilo de codificação, pode corromper a memória, o que é pior que o *slicing*, que nem ocorreria.

> O *slicing* pode ocorrer dentro de um vetor de dados homogêneos? Ou ele está restrito a dados heterogêneos?

Realmente homogêneos não pode. A não ser por uma deficiência de implementação da linguagem, mas descarto isso.

## Como ocorre o *slicing*.

O *slicing* ocorre quando você espera um objeto e vem um outro com estrutura estendida.

Por estrutura entenda o estado. O *slicing*  não é sobre comportamentos, então se um tipo derivado não adiciona nada ao objeto base, você está livre do *slicing*. Alguns dirão que nesse caso sequer houve uma herança de fato.

Vamos ver:

```
class Base
    x : int

class Derivada : Base
    y : int

b := Base()
d := Derivada() { x = 1, y = 2 }
b = d //funciona porque d é do tipo de b, nem toda linguagem deixa implicitamente
print b.x //sem problemas, dá 1
//print b.y //daria erro porque em b não tem y, então não temos problema aqui
d = b
print d.x //beleza, dá 1
print d.y //agora pode, d tem um y, mas imprime 2?
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/Slicing.cpp).

Acontece que `b` não tem o elemento `y`, ele se perde, quando transforma e coloca `b` no tipo derivado só o `x` existe, o `y` teria um valor *default* (provavelmente), aí acontece o *slicing* no `b = d`.

Em um vetor há uma atribuição assim. Se `Vector<Base>` é usado quando você faz `v[0] = d` está fazendo o mesmo que `b = d`, ocorre o *slicing*. Em cada variável de `v` só tem espaço para o tipo `Base`, ou seja, só tem espaço para um `int`, quando você tenta colocar um tipo que é considerado compatível ali mas ele tem mais dados, estes serão descartados, então o `d` que tinha dois `int`s perderá o segundo.

Por isso que recomenda-se evitar o uso de tipos por valor a não ser onde há ganhos claros, sejam obviamente valores básicos [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) ou você precise muito de uma otimização e saiba muito o que está fazendo e entenda todos os fenômenos que podem ocorrer, entre eles o "esquartejamento" (o termo não deveria ser *slashing*?).

Quando você usa um [tipo por referência ou lida com um tipo por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) como referência o problema não ocorre por causa da [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Nestes tipos o valor básico armazenado é um ponteiro sempre do mesmo tamanho, nunca ocorre o *slicing*. O dado realmente está em outro lugar e pode ter tamanhos diferentes. Claro que em linguagens de tipagem completamente forte todos serão do mesmo tipo base (sem [covariância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101) pode vazar).

Lembrando que existem várias formas de atribuição (cópia), uma delas é passar um dado para uma função. Quando é passado por referência a cópia é só do ponteiro e não do objeto em si, então podemos dizer que ocorre uma mudança e não uma cópia. Só a cópia do objeto pode retalhá-lo.

Outra forma de resolver isto é criar um construtor de cópia que lide com a questão de forma adequada, mas nem sempre compensa.

Note que este caso que exemplifiquei não é um problema real porque o compilador não deixa. Mesmo em C++ na forma como se costuma fazer não tem como dar errado. Agora o que pode dar errado e você perceber tarde demais:

```
struct A {
    A(int a) : a_var(a) {}
    int a_var;
};

struct B : public A {
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b_var(b) {}
    int b_var;
};

B &getB() { //importante o retorno por referência
    static B b(1, 2);
    return b;
}

int main() {
    A a(3);
    a = getB();
    // a.a_var == 1, b.b_var não copiado para a
    B b2(3, 4);
    A &a2 = b2;
    a2 = getB();
    cout << b2.a_var << b2.b_var; //dá 1 e 4, misturou os objetos
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/Slicing2.cpp).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

A maioria das linguagens não sofre com isto. C++ é alto e baixo de nível demais, essa combinação causa o problema. O *slicing* ocorre em diversas linguagens, mas o compilador identifica e proíbe.