# Qual a vantagem dos objetos em PHP serem passados por referências por padrão?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, objetos, referência

A partir do PHP 5 uma variável objeto não contém mais o próprio objeto como valor. Ela contém um identificador do objeto que permite que os "acessadores" do objeto encontrem o objeto real.

Recentemente passei por um pequeno problema, onde eu tinha uma função que recebia um objeto como parâmetro, e na função eu criei uma variável para receber o valor do objeto, então eu precisei modificar a variável, mas **qualquer alteração** que eu realizava na variável, também alterava meu objeto.

Consegui resolver esse problema clonando meu objeto, mas fiquei com o seguinte questionamento: Qual a vantagem dos objetos em PHP serem passados por referências por padrão?

Comment: Na verdade esse é o padrão de passagem de valores de tipos não primitivos na maioria das linguagens. Esse seu código de exemplo não faz muito sentido... Se o argumento chegasse como uma cópia do valor, por que você precisaria atribuir para outra variável `$bar`? Bastaria retornar `$foo`.

Comment: Vale lembrar que mesmo o `clone` nativo do PHP faz apenas a cópia rasa (ou superficial) do objeto. Se necessitar de uma cópia profunda (ou completa) terá que implementar manualmente através do método `__clone`.

Comment: A principal vantagem é economizar memória, pois passar por referência evita a criação de cópias dos objetos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tenho minhas dúvidas se a afirmação do primeiro parágrafo está correta, na verdade nem sei se ela está clara.

> Qual a vantagem dos objetos em PHP serem passados por referências por padrão?

Basicamente duas:

- não precisar copiar o objeto, o que muitas vezes pode ser uma operação relativamente custosa porque alguns objetos tendem ser um pouco grandes (embora pra PHP isso não faça tanta diferença assim e talvez eles tenham feito porque outras linguagens são assim);
- poder modificar os valores do objeto em qualquer lugar e refletir por toda a aplicação, exatamente o que está achando que é um defeito é considerado uma vantagem.

Existem algumas vantagens derivas, como poder usar polimorfismo, evitar [*slicing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286437/101), e outros. Uma referência é uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), que dá mais flexibilidade para fazer várias coisas.

Raros os casos que não deseja que uma alteração se reflita no objeto de forma global, e se está precisando fazer isto questione se não está fazendo algo errado. Se realmente precisa disto seria bom analisar se este objeto cumpre um papel correto no sistema e se não deveria ser formulado de outra forma.

Outra questão a pensar é se não poder mexer no objeto é algo próprio dele e ele mesmo deveria garantir a [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101) ou se é um caso pontual que merece uma cópia.

> qualquer alteração que eu realizava na variável, também alterava meu objeto

Isso não é verdade, se você alterar o objeto todo na variável não irá mexer no outro objeto. Justamente por um objeto ser por referência se você alterar a referência você estará colocando outro objeto na variável e portanto o objeto original não sofrerá alterações. Note que a alteração ocorre só na variável, portanto se passou como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) não mexe no argumento, apenas no parâmetro que é a variável, então se sair do método não faz mais sentido esperar essa alteração refletida em alguma outra variável do método chamador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: @manieri o código informado não é o código real do problema que eu tive, como eu consegui resolver, eu só coloquei esse exemplo de código pra tentar deixar claro minha dúvida.

Comment: Aconteceu o oposto, um código não real geralmente deixa menos claro.

Comment: Realmente aconteceu isso mesmo rsrs, removi o código já que não estava agregando nada a pergunta. ;)